# How to replace this.$parent.$emit in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, migration, linter, vuejs3

I have migrated my application to Vue 3.

Now my linter shows a deprecation error, documented here: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-deprecated-events-api.html.

The documentation shows how to replace `this.$emit` with the `mitt` library, but it doesn't show how to replace `this.$parent.$emit`.

Comment: did you migrate your application from Vue 2?

Comment: Yes, I am migrating from Vue 2

Comment: In Vue 3, $on, $off and $once instance methods were removed. You will no longer be able to implement the event emitter interface using an eventHub for example. You will however be able to continue using $emit as it will remain part of the existing API as it's used to trigger event handlers declaratively attached by a parent component.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your child component:

```
setup(props, { emit }) {
   ...
   emit('yourEvent', yourDataIfYouHaveAny);
}
```

Your parent component:

```
<your-child @yourEvent="onYourEvent" />
```

...

```
onYourEvent(yourDataIfYouHaveAny) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With script setup syntax, you can do:

```
<script setup>
    const emit = defineEmits(['close', 'test'])
    
    const handleClose = () => {
        emit('close')
        emit('test', { anything: 'yes' })
    }
</script>
```

No need to import anything from 'vue'. `defineEmits` is included.

Read more here: https://learnvue.co/2020/01/4-vue3-composition-api-tips-you-should-know/

Comment: Should be defineEmits

Answer (score 1):

Due to the composition api, it  allows you to use the **$attrs** inherited in each component to now fulfill this need.

I assume that you are using this.$parent.emit because you know the the child will always be part of the same parent. How do I simulate the above behavior with **$attrs**?

Lets say I have a table containing row components. However I wish to respond to row clicks in table's parent.

*Table Definition*

```
 <template>
  <row v-bind="$attrs" ></row>
 </template>
```

*Row Definition*

```
<template name="row" :item="row" @click=onClick(row)>
  Your Row 
</template>

export default {
    emits: {
      row_clicked: () =>{
       return true
      }
   }, 
   onClick(rowData){
     this.$emit('row_clicked',rowData)
  }
}
```

Finally, a component containing your table definition, where you have a method to handle the click.

```
<table
@row_clicked=clicked() 
>

</table
```

Your table component should effectively apply @row_clicked to the row component thus triggering when row emits the event.

Answer (score 0):

There is similar way of doing it by using the `context` argument that is passed in second argument inside the child component (the one that will emit the event)

```
setup(props, context){
     context.emit('myEventName')
}
```

...then emit it by calling the `context.emit` method within the `setup` method.

In your parent component you can listen to it using the handler like so:

```
<MyParentComponent @myEventName="handleMyEventName" />
```

Of course, in the setup method of the `MyParentComponent` component you can declare the handler like this

```
//within <script> tag of MyParentComponent
setup(props){
    const handleMyEventName() => {
            ...
    }
    return { handleMyEventName }
}
```